# Nokogiri: apply class to element that has a certain descendant

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Let's say I have this html that has various depths of descendants and a mixture of element types:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <u><span class="duh">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </span></u>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to apply a class of bex to all the foos that contain classes of bar so it looks like:

```
<div class="bex">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
<div class="bex">
    <u><span class="duh">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </span></u>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
```

How wld I do that with ruby/nokogiri? Tried all sorts of things and can't quite get it. Thanks.

Edit: closed the duh, oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a long time wondering why the second foo wasn't found.
Your data is broken, `"duh` isn't closed.

To select the nodes, you can use :

```
doc.xpath("//div[@class='foo' and .//div[@class='bar']]")
```

As an example :

```
data = %q(<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <u><span class="duh">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </span></u>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="baz"></div>
</div>)

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(data)

doc.xpath("//div[@class='foo' and .//div[@class='bar']]").each do |node|
  node["class"] = 'bex'
end

puts doc
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Sorry about not closing the duh, duh. If anyone feels like explaining how this cld be done via css targeting rather than with xpath I'd be interested in knowing.